# Insert a date into SQL query read from file

Tags: python

I have a long SQL query that lives in its own file, and I'm curious if there's a way to sub in a date from my primary script when I read in the text.

```
with open('MyQuery.sql', 'r') as rawSQL:
    sql = rawSQL.read()
```

MyQuery.sql

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE
  date >= '2022-10-10'
```

I'd like to sub in today's date for '2022-10-10'. I know if I had the query in plain text in my main script I could just do this:

```
from datetime import date

today_date = date.today()

sql = f"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date >= {today_date};"
```

But I'm not sure how to do something equivalent when reading from a separate file.

And I'm assuming there's a better way to do this than matching a RegEx pattern for date and substituting.

My desired result is a SQL string matching my MyQuery.sql sample, with the date inserted from `today_date` instead of hardcoded.

Comment: The right way would be to change your query so it has the `?` substitution character where you need to fill in values.  Then pass the date when you make the call, as in `db.execute( sql, (today_date,))`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I had myself all twisted up on that one and this makes way more sense.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get current date directly in your .sql file.

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE
  date >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: That is a good point. To the specifics of my question, Tim's recommendation of passing the data to the query as a parameter makes more sense in my opinion, but for certain use cases this is definitely a nice clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, based on Tim's feedback, this worked for me:

Update the .sql file to this, replacing the date with `?`:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE
  date >= ?;
```

And then for my use-case, I'm ultimately writing the results of this query to `.csv` and I'm pulling the results with `pd.read_sql()`, and we can pass `start_date` via `params`.

```
with con:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    data = pd.read_sql(sql, con, params=[start_date])
```